# Export Localization builds with macOS causing trouble: requires minimum platform version

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I got a project that I am developing for iOS only with a local Swift package that I want to localize, so I added the `Resources` dir and added a `defaultLocalization` line in the Package.swift. That local package has a dependency on [GRDBQuery](https://github.com/groue/GRDBQuery/blob/main/Package.swift).

Now when I want to export the localized strings, I get this error:

[image]

I don't even use macOS in the Entities package:

[image]

This is a really annoying error. Does anyone know how to fix it? I can NOT add macOS as a target. Why does it say 'this target supports 10.13'?

I can localize my main target fine when my local package does NOT use localization. As soon as it does, I see in the logging that it uses macOS to build. When the local packages do not have localization, iOS SDK is used.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Xcode 14.2 and SPM.
Resorted to `xcodebuild` to specify SDK.

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath . -project MyProject.xcodeproj -exportLanguage en -sdk iphoneos16.2
```

Unfortunately, `exportLocalizations` builds all targets, and one of my Targets is a Watch, so i had to `#if os(watchOS)` to exclude all that code. It doesn't let you specify multiple SDKs. Also tried excluding that target from Localization in the project, but that seemed to be ignored by xcodebuild. Nor did specifying target OR scheme help